# Feature Image Showing Too Big

Tags: featured-post

My feature images keeping showing up too large, I have tried to resize the images and re-upload but they are still showing up too big.

I have tried to put in CSS code and gone onto Media setttings but haven't had much luck yet.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom featured image sizes in your theme’s functions file that can then be called in your theme’s template files.
**Read more** [add-custom-featured-image-sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/#add-custom-featured-image-sizes)